# C# - Generar un archivo XML desde una fuente de datos

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo un dilema, ya que estoy intentando generar un archivo XML apartir de una fuente de datos, tengo una variable string, la cual me guarda un formato XML que me retorna mi base de datos, lo que quisiera saber es ¿cómo puedo generar un archivo y guardarlo en un directorio apartir de esa fuente de datos? Estoy ocupando c# como lenguaje, no sé si pudieran ayudarme. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una variable `string` con el xml para persistirlo en un archivo solo tienes que usar

```
string xmlString = "....";
string fullPath = @"c:\...\archivoxml.xml";

File.WriteAllText(fullPath, xmlString);
```

Recuerda definir el

```
using System.IO;
```

para poder usar el `WriteAllText()`